# Receiving an UDP Packet from Arduino in a CrossbarServer in Python

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, arduino-uno, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm new using WAMP protocol and CrossbarIO servers that are based on the WAMP protocol. The problem is. I have and Arduino Uno + EthernetShield and I want to send the information to the CrossbarServer. 
The Arduino Uno has not support for Autobahn or WAMP or Crossbar. I just can send normal packages via UDP and websocket with an UNO+Ethernet.
Is there someway that I can read this UDP packet in the CrossbarServer from the arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do so directly at the moment. For the time being, you need to connect the Uno to some component which accepts messages from the Uno and can talk WAMP as well.

We are working on a C library for lower-end devices, but as far as I can tell (I'm not directly involved) something with the specs of the Uno will remain out of the scope of WAMP even then since the initial plan is that the library itself will consume about 8k of RAM.

Comment: thanks a lot! Nice work. I hope that when you finish the lib I could test! Best regards!